# Xamarin Custom renderer ContentView issues

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, custom-renderer

I have written a custom renderer for iOS to create a chatbubble programmatically. The main chat bubble inherits from ContentView, this is done to allow me to add a Label as it's sole child. For the most part it works well but as soon as there are multiple lines of text it behaves very strangely, namely the text overflows and doesn't respect the parents boundaries(reminds me of when I was a teenager).

When I replace this custom control with a regular frame everything seems to work well. I am calculating the required height by overriding the Draw(CGRect ) call

Code here :

```
ppublic class ChatBubbleRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<ChatBubbleFrame>
{
    public ChatBubbleRenderer()
    {
        this.ClipsToBounds = false;
    }

    public override void Draw(CGRect rect1)
    {
        var rect = Frame;
        var currentContext = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        var properRect = AdjustForThickness(rect);
        HandleShapeDraw(currentContext, properRect);
    } 

    protected RectangleF AdjustForThickness(CGRect rect)
    {
        var x = rect.X + Element.Padding.Left;
        var y = rect.Y + Element.Padding.Top;
        var width = rect.Width - ((Element.Padding.Left + (int)Element.StrokeWidth) * 2);
        var height = rect.Height - ((Element.Padding.Top + (int)Element.StrokeWidth) * 2);
        return new RectangleF((float)x, (float)y, (float)width, (float)height);
    }

    protected void HandleShapeDraw(CGContext currentContext, RectangleF rect)
    {
        var path = new CGPath();
        var cr = (float)Element.CornerRadius;
        var hl = (float)Element.HandleLength;
        var x = rect.Left+hl;
        var y = (float)rect.Top;

        var startLeft = x;
        var startTop = y;
        var startRight = rect.Right - hl;
        var startBottom = rect.Bottom ;
        var centerX = x + cr;
        var centerY = y + cr;
        var width = (float)rect.Width - hl - hl;
        var height = (float)rect.Height ;

        if (Element.HandleIsBottomRight)
        {
            path.AddArc(centerX, centerY, cr, (float)Math.PI, (float)Math.PI * 3f / 2f, false);
            x = startRight - cr;
            //line to top right arc
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);

            //top right arc
            centerX = x;
            path.AddArc(centerX, centerY, cr, (float)Math.PI * 3f / 2f, 0, false);
            x = x + cr;

            //bring y down to top of triangle
            y = y + height;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);

            //chat handle
            x = x + hl;
            y = y + hl;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);
            //to bottom left arc

            x = startLeft + cr;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);

            //bottom left arc
            centerX = x;
            centerY = y - cr;
            path.AddArc(centerX, centerY, cr, (float)Math.PI / 2f, (float)Math.PI, false); //false to rotate clockwise
        }
        else
        {
            //line to top right arc
            path.MoveToPoint(x, y);
            x = startRight - cr;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);

            //top right arc
            centerX = x;
            path.AddArc(centerX, centerY, cr, (float)Math.PI * 3f / 2f, 0, false);

            //line to bottom right arc
            x = x + cr;
            y = y + height - cr;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);

            //bottom right arc
            centerX = x - cr;
            centerY = y;
            path.AddArc(centerX, centerY, cr, 0f, (float)Math.PI / 2f, false);

            //line to bottom left arc
            x = startLeft + cr;
            y = y + cr;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);

            //bottom left arc
            centerX = x;
            centerY = y - cr;
            path.AddArc(centerX, centerY, cr, (float)Math.PI / 2f, (float)Math.PI, false); //false to rotate clockwise

            //line to handle
            x = startLeft;
            y = startTop + hl;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);
            x = x - hl;
            y = startTop;
            path.AddLineToPoint(x, y);
        } 

        path.CloseSubpath();
        HandleStandardDraw(currentContext, rect, () => currentContext.AddPath(path));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// A simple method for handling our drawing of the shape. This method is called differently for each type of shape
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="currentContext">Current context.</param>
    /// <param name="rect">Rect.</param>
    /// <param name="createPathForShape">Create path for shape.</param>
    /// <param name="lineWidth">Line width.</param>
    protected virtual void HandleStandardDraw(CGContext currentContext, RectangleF rect, Action createPathForShape, float? lineWidth = null)
    {
        currentContext.SetLineWidth(lineWidth ?? Element.StrokeWidth);
        currentContext.SetFillColor(Element.InnerColor.ToCGColor());
        currentContext.SetStrokeColor(Element.StrokeColor.ToCGColor());

        createPathForShape();

        currentContext.DrawPath(CoreGraphics.CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
    }
}
```

Chat bubble Code

```html
public class ChatBubbleFrame : ContentView
{
 public ChatBubbleFrame()
 {
 }

 public static readonly BindableProperty HandleIsBottomRightProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
  propertyName: "HandleIsBottomRight",
  returnType: typeof(bool),
  declaringType: typeof(ChatBubbleFrame),
  defaultValue: true
 );

 public static readonly BindableProperty InnerColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
  propertyName: "InnerColor",
  returnType: typeof(Color),
  declaringType: typeof(ChatBubbleFrame),
  defaultValue: Color.Default
 );

 public static readonly BindableProperty HandleLengthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    propertyName: "HandleLength",
    returnType: typeof(float),
    declaringType: typeof(ChatBubbleFrame),
    defaultValue: 2f
   );

 public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
  propertyName: "StrokeColor",
  returnType: typeof(Color),
  declaringType: typeof(ChatBubbleFrame),
  defaultValue: Color.Default
 );

 public static readonly BindableProperty StrokeWidthProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
  propertyName: "StrokeWidth",
  returnType: typeof(float),
  declaringType: typeof(ChatBubbleFrame),
  defaultValue: 1f
 );

 public static readonly BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
  propertyName: "CornerRadius",
  returnType: typeof(float),
  declaringType: typeof(ChatBubbleFrame),
  defaultValue: 0f
 );

 public bool HandleIsBottomRight
 {
  get { return (bool)GetValue(HandleIsBottomRightProperty); }
  set { SetValue(HandleIsBottomRightProperty, value); }
 }

 public float HandleLength
 {
  get { return (float)GetValue(HandleLengthProperty); }
  set { SetValue(HandleLengthProperty, value); }
 }

 public Color StrokeColor
 {
  get { return (Color)GetValue(StrokeColorProperty); }
  set { SetValue(StrokeColorProperty, value); }
 }

 public Color InnerColor
 {
  get { return (Color)GetValue(InnerColorProperty); }
  set { SetValue(InnerColorProperty, value); }
 }

 public float StrokeWidth
 {
  get { return (float)GetValue(StrokeWidthProperty); }
  set { SetValue(StrokeWidthProperty, value); }
 }

 public float CornerRadius
 {
  get
  {
   return (float)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
  }

  set
  {
   SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
  }
 }
}
```

Xaml snippet

```html
<controls:ChatBubbleFrame x:Name="OtherUserBubble"                   
                            HandleIsBottomRight="False"
                            StrokeColor="{StaticResource Color13}"
                            InnerColor="White"
                            StrokeWidth="1"
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            HandleLength="7"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            Padding="-1,10,10,10"
                            Margin="35,0,10,0"
                            Grid.Column="0">
    <StackLayout Margin="17,10,12,18">
         <Label Text="{Binding Entity.CommentText }"
                Style="{StaticResource Typo23}"
                LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                Margin="0,6,10,0" />
    </StackLayout>
</controls:ChatBubbleFrame>
```

Screenshots of a good message bubble and a terrible message bubble

[image: No problem here] 
[image: text overflowing]